# How do I get to view someone else his solution?

Tags: visual-studio, version-control, azure-devops

I have a little question.. Me and a friend of mine are working on a project for school. Now we are trying to use VisualStudio Online, so we can work on the project together and not having to exchange our files all the time.

My friend set up the project and placed it in his 'Workspace', now I'm connected to him.. His 'VisualStudio online' part thingy (not sure how to call it). Now when I try to get into the solution.. well.. I just can't find it..

As you can see, I am connected: http://prntscr.com/8h2paz.
I also already tried to set up a workspace at my own computer, but I still can't get it working..

Sorry for my bad grammer etc.. Maybe someone could help me out.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Perhaps this? [Set up Team Foundation Version Control on your dev machine](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181384.aspx)

Comment: @crashmstr Sorry, that didn't help me out.. Thanks for your help though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to work with TFS version controlled project, you need to:

1. Have required permissions to Check in, Check out and Read that project.
2. Have a workspace on your machine to map that project to a folder on your dev machine.

However, your screenshot said that there is no workspace on your machine. So, you need to click the **Configure your workspace** link configure the workspace on your machine.

[image]

Choose the server path you want to map, and a local folder you want to map to. And click the **Map & Get button** to create the server-local mapping and get latest version files to local folder. 
[image]

To be sure that your friend already grant you the required permissions to work with that project. Right-click the project in the Source Control Explorer, select Advanced -> Security. Set Check In, Check Out and Read permissions to be Allow.

[image]